# TCPDF - Add Page in case content does not fit on one page

Tags: php, tcpdf

```
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetTitle($category->shortName);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11, '', true);
foreach($html as $htm) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell($w = 0, $h = 0, $x = '', $y = '', $htm, $border = 0, $ln = 0, $fill = 0, $reset = true, $align = '', $autopadding = true);
}
```

The array `$html` contains content that ususally fits on one page, but sometimes exceed its bonds. For these cases, I want to add an additional page for the overflow. How do I do that?

Comment: First problem the correct use of writehtmlcell is:
`// writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true)`
Second TCPDF do it automatically

Comment: Ok, but where is the difference to what I wrote?

Comment: example : `($w = 0`  is `( 0`

Comment: well, that does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

What finally helped was using `$pdf->writeHTML` instead of `$pdf->writeHTMLCell`

Comment: Interesting... So no need for  setAutoPageBreak?

Comment: yes, exactly, since AutoPageBreak is set to true by default